# Stack Overflow logo in footer is misleading (on Meta)

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, logo, footer

On Meta, the SO logo displayed in the footer is the main site logo, but it actually links to Meta.

I think it should either link to the main site or be the dark Meta logo if it's supposed to link to Meta.

I clicked it expecting to navigate to the main site.

[image]

Comment: ... How has no-one noticed that before?

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe noone has ever clicked the logo in a footer :P
At least on meta :)

Comment: There's a site footer?

Comment: Since I don't hang out in meta much, I always scream in panic when I click the StackOverflow logo on the top left expecting it to go back to the non-meta site. It doesn't because I'm blind.

Comment: Also, the "Questions" link under "STACK OVERFLOW" links here as well, which ... nope, I can't do it. I can't care about this bug. It's not in me.

Comment: @Will: ... while the capital letter text links to non-meta

Comment: Iv'e never scrolled down below "Post Your Answer".

Comment: @Cerbrus I often find it hard to go back to the main site. I've clicked that logo countless times

Comment: Why SE takes so much time to fix this type of bug? It is really hard to believe. You should able to fix this types of issues within a few hours....

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson don't worry, it should be fixed in 6-8 weeks. I'm sure they have other more pressing matters to deal with at the moment.

Comment: @Aaroninus Almost every web site has footers even you don't know.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Take "this type of bug" and multiply it by about 100 (or more...), then add a bunch of new feature development, not to mention checking to make sure this wasn't done on purpose for some reason, and you'll start to see why you can't just fix every little bug within a few hours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've changed the URL to point to Stack Overflow, given that the logo is indeed that of Stack Overflow and not of Meta Stack Overflow.

With you in the next build.