# Stack Overflow Meta has Stack Overflow's Footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

Not sure if this is in effect after new design changes but I saw that unlike other Meta sites, Stack Overflow Meta has the footer of Stack Overflow's as shown in the image. Is it by-design?

[image: Pic1]

Comment: I would actually argue that all meta  sites footers should be that of their main site.  I would say this should be by design.

Comment: I don't mind it to keep it as is but as an end user (especially new user) wouldn't that look little inconsistent and confusing?

Comment: Maybe but meta.so is part of stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonH:  [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) has its own footer which is different than [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Arqade Meta has its own footer too, separate from Arqade.

Comment: [Meta Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) also has a different footer than [es.so]

Comment: Sounds like there's a great number of sites that need to be corrected, then :-D

Comment: The Meta effect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shog's right that it's not a new thing, but ya know, that logo/name situation never made sense to me either.

As of a few minutes ago, MSO footer now refers to "Meta Stack Overflow", links back to MSO like other sites do, and displays the correct logo.

Comment: Just for overruling  Shog9's status-bydesign *and* put hours in to make those changes is a +1 from me. It looks awesome.

Answer (score 2):

It's not new; the SO/MSO footers have been *very* similar for close to a year now. In fact, [here's a bug report from last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356524/stack-overflow-logo-in-footer-is-misleading-on-meta) about the very logo you highlight in your screenshot.

It's not the *exactly* the same either: the SO footer has more links in it:

[image: Jobs, Developer Jobs Directory, Salary Calculator]

...and that darker background color.

Comment: The text colors are also different, as well as chrome's dev tools eye dropper tells me the orange coloration of the stacks are slightly different, but the inbox under the stack is the same color

Comment: Roger. But then are you planning to make the changes across other stack exchange network sites? Isn't it inconsistent that for some site it has their own footer and for some it hasn't?

Comment: Long-term, the goal is to use one theme (with minor customizations) across all sites, @Karan. However, Stack Overflow's footer will likely always have some notable differences due to the presence of Jobs, Teams, etc.